# AJAX JQuery cant fetch data from url in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this code in my script. I use this so that when user have selected the #doctorSelect, it shows something but in my console.log it's not showing anything. only [] and when I tried to search `localhost:8000/dashboard/doctors/1` it's showing error of `unexpected end of json input at json.parse (anonymous)`.

this is my script:

```
function handleDoctorSelectChange() {
    const selectedOption = $('#doctorSelect option:selected');
    const doctorID = selectedOption.val();
    console.log(doctorID);
    if (selectedOption.data('doctor')) {
        const doctor = selectedOption.data('doctor');
        const doctorIDs = doctor.id;
        const doctorName = doctor.name;
        console.log(doctorIDs, doctorName);
        const ajaxURL = '/dashboard/doctors/' + doctorIDs;
        console.log('AJAX URL:', ajaxURL);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: ajaxURL,
            success: function (additionalData) {
                console.log(additionalData);
                if ('data' in additionalData) {
                    const additionalData1 = additionalData.data;
                    console.log(additionalData1);
                    if ('id' in additionalData1 && 'name' in additionalData1) {
                        console.log('Doctor Data:', additionalData1);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Properties not found in additionalData');
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error('Data key not found in the response');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my controller:

```
public function getDoctor($id)
{
    return response()->json(Doctor::find($id));
}
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::controller(AppointmentController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('dashboard/doctors/{id}', 'getDoctor');
});
```

I've tried asking ChatGPT to help me, but it still error. I get the number 1-10 which is doctorID, doctorName, and even ajaxURL(/dashboard/doctors/1) from console.log.
this is what I expected

```
"data": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Dr. Dr. Dax Ondricka DDS",
        "service": "Orthopedic",
        "work_days": "[\"Wednesday\",\"Thursday\"]",
        "start_work": "06:00:00",
        "end_work": "08:00:00",
        "created_at": "2024-02-05T05:49:43.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-02-05T05:49:43.000000Z"
    }
```

so that i could get start_work and end_work, and then send to blade view.

Comment: _"it's showing error of unexpected end of json input"_ - please use your browser dev tools to check what response the request actually got.

Comment: I use edge when i open localhost:8000/dashboard/doctors/1 and i have this in response [] with this error in console SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). the view is like a this
[img]https://i.imgur.com/QedIGUP.png[/img]

Answer (score -1):

Your AJAX request setup seems correct, but you might be facing issues with either the server route handling or the data you're expecting to receive. So try to debug the AJAX request.

But despite your Laravel route and controller method looks fine, could be a good idea ensure that the Doctor::find($id) method returns a result as expected. If Doctor::find($id) returns null, Laravel's response()->json(null) will return an empty response, which could lead to the "unexpected end of JSON input" error you're seeing.

So you can modify your getDoctor method to check if a doctor is found and return a more informative response if not:

```
public function getDoctor($id)
{
    $doctor = Doctor::find($id);
    if (!$doctor) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Doctor not found'], 404);
    }

    return response()->json($doctor);
}
```

and in your success callback function you should checks if 'data' in additionalData, but based on your controller's response, the JSON returned doesn't seem to be wrapped in a data object at the top level. Instead, it directly returns the Doctor object. You should try directly access the properties of additionalData:

```
success: function (additionalData) {
    console.log(additionalData);
    // Directly check if 'id' and 'name' exist in additionalData
    if ('id' in additionalData && 'name' in additionalData) {
        console.log('Doctor Data:', additionalData);
     } else {
        console.error('Properties not found in additionalData');
    }
}
```

and make sure the URL you're trying to fetch from (/dashboard/doctors/1)

Comment: Why this check down?

Comment: It's an unclear question lacking useful troubleshooting details, and your answer is just a guess giving generic advice

Comment: There is no guess here,  but a way to investigate the problem...